# Issue with using outdated package in R

Tags: c++, r, package

I'm trying to use an old package (surv2sample, last updated in 2012) that's no longer available in the CRAN repository. I was able to install an archived 2012 version of the package from GitHub (including a 2017 commit) and it appeared to load without a problem. However, when I attempt to run one of the functions in the package, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in .C("twosample_neyman", as.double(tim), as.integer(evt), as.integer(grp),  : 
  "twosample_neyman" not available for .C() for package "surv2sample"
```

From reading through previous online posts on this issue, I understand that adding "useDynLib('packagename')" to the NAMESPACE file with the package can resolve this error. The commit from 2017 already added that. Any other thoughts on how to resolve this error?

Comment: You might want to use an older version of R that was around back when that package was released. Lots of stuff has changed in R since 2012.

Comment: The 2007 and 2012 versions *are* in the CRAN repository. In the main page https://cran.r-project.org click Packages then Archive. Then look for it paying atention that lower case letters come after all upper case letters. And find it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/surv2sample/).

Comment: @Rui Barradas Yes, I understand the archived versions can be found on there. It does not change the error message I receive.

Comment: @MrFlick I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look into the `checkpoint` library: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html